# Java Spring: send list from Ajax to Controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, controller

I'm trying to send an array of
[this Json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLxKg.png)
data using this Ajax in a JSP:

```
$.ajax({
        url:  'agregarSeleccion',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(lista),
        success:function(dataP){
            //Successs
        error: function (jqXhr) { 
            swal("Error","","error");
        }
   });
```

To this controller in Java (Spring framework):

```
private List<Seleccion> seleccionados = new ArrayList<Seleccion>();

@RequestMapping("/agregarSeleccion")
@ResponseBody
public List<Seleccion> agregar(Seleccion obj) {
    seleccionados.add(obj);
    return seleccionados;
}
```

The *"Seleccion"* object it's an entity that has some of the attributes of the JSON that I sent from Ajax, the "*seleccionados"* is a list that saves the array received, but when I send it, the obj param always return a null object and Ajax sends the error function, I think the problem is that I'm sending an array to an *Object*, but I can't figure how to solve it

Seleccion object model:

```
public class Seleccion {
    private int idProducto;
    private String nombre;
    private double precio;
    private int cantidad;
    private double totalParcial;
   //Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ResponseEntity and update you controller like the below snippet;

**Test Data**

```
[
{
    idProducto : 1,
    nombre : 'Test1',
    precio : 1.5,
    cantidad : 1,
    totalParcial : 2.5
}
]
```

**Your Ajax** (I changed datatype back to **json**);

```
$.ajax({
        url:  'agregarSeleccion',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(lista),
        success:function(dataP){
            console.log(dataP);
        },
        error: function (jqXhr) { 
            swal("Error","","error");
        }
   });
```

**Your Controller** (Notice a variable is declared outside method as well , added **allAll** method to add list , Changed **return type** at the end)

```
List<Seleccion> seleccionados;
@RequestMapping("/agregarSeleccion")
public ResponseEntity<?> agregar(@Valid @RequestBody List<Seleccion> obj) {
    
    seleccionados = new ArrayList<Seleccion>();
    System.out.println("result"+ obj.toString());
    seleccionados.addAll(obj);  
    return new ResponseEntity<>(seleccionados, HttpStatus.OK);
    
}
```

Comment: No result, if I change List to ResponseEntity in the controller and in the "seleccionados " variable the code shows and error about Instance

Comment: I edited my answer -> agregar(@Valid @RequestBody List<Seleccion> obj) added a list inside the method signature with RequestBody annotation.

Comment: I get the an "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]"
Also the "seleccionados.add(obj)" still with the error "The method add(Seleccion) in the type List<Seleccion> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Seleccion>)"

Comment: change datatype in ajax to -> dataType : "html" that will solve media type error.

Comment: I change the datatype (and the JSON.stringify(lista) just in case) but I get the same 2 errors

Comment: Can you please add the code for model object for Seleccion.

Comment: Done, these 4 attributes are the data extracted from the Json file, while the double "totalParcial" gets its value from cantidad*precio

Comment: I edited my answer and added some testdata. you can also test this with postman.

Comment: Okay at least I don't have errors on the code, but the `Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported]` stills appearing when executing (already tried again with dataType 'html')

Comment: Hi i modified the ajax -> remove datatype and add contentType: 'application/json'. check the full ajax code above (datatype attribute is removed) . your success callback was also missing a closing bracket } i added it to the above snippet.

Comment: Great It passed the error, now I have a FK problem, as you can see on the attached img, the "idProducto" value comes from in a Product array inside the Json, causing that "precio" and "cantidad" comes with its values and IdProduct comes with 0, is there a way to get the value?

Comment: In this case you need to add product array and other objects into seleccionados. Check the OOP concept Composition ( Has - A relationship ) for more details. At the moment the relationship between product object and other objects are not mapped together. you need to map it together first. Cheers.

Comment: Sure buddy anytime.